# Numpy apply function to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

For example, I have function:

```
f1 = lambda x: x % 2
```

If I want to modify `array = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)` I can do `f1(array)`. Everything works as expected:

```
[0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
```

If I change function to:

```
f2 = lambda x: 0
print(f2(array))
```

gives me `0` while I expected `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`. How to achieve consistency?

Comment: The return value of `f2` is not an array. Nothing unexpected happening here.

Comment: you can use `f2 = lambda x: x-x`

Comment: I expected that `f2` will iterate over `array` and evaluate every element then store it to a resulting array.

Comment: Python functions don't automatically iterate over their arguments; the expression `x % 2` does (when `x` is an `np.array`).

Comment: you want the mod... np.mod(array, 2) => ,,, array([0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.])

Comment: It's the `%` thats doing the iteration in the first case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below code to achieve desirable output

```
import numpy as np
array = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
f2 = lambda x: x-x
print(f2(array))
```

Comment: how about if the array was array of array ?

Comment: Thanks, @user702846 for your concern, in that case, we need some changes. The above code works for the mentioned case

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more explicit than previous answer :

```
import numpy as np
array = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
f2 = lambda x: np.zeros_like(x)
print(f2(array))
```

Documentation for `numpy.zeros_like`: Return an array of zeros with the same shape and type as a given array.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over an array, evaluate the function for every element, then store it to a resulting array, a list iterator works consistently:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.linspace(0, 5, 6)
f1 = lambda x: x % 2
f2 = lambda x: 0

print ([f1(x) for x in array])
```

**[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]**

```
print ([f2(x) for x in array])
```

**[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]**